# Background DIV element covering all the others - how to solve?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to have a page with a responsive layout that has the following elements (see picture):

[image: Layout example]

Legend:

1. "folds" for the menu means that it just becomes a small button, which unfolds the menu again on click);
2. When the left menu folds, the content and canvas div need to slide to the left side of the page. When it unfolds, they get pushed to the right again;
3. The bottom menu 2 is folded by default (you can only see a button). If you click it, then the small menu opens (above the other elements);
4. The content div is scrollable;
5. The elements both in content and canvas should be selectable;

Right now I have the following code:

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="menu></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
<div>
```

The position of background is "relative", the menu and canvas are set as "fixed".

The problem right now is that something (background div) is covering all the other elements, so I can't select the elements inside the content div and the canvas div.

I tried setting z-index correctly (lowest for the background, highest for the canvas) – didn't work.

I don't understand what the problem is.

Can somebody help me, please? Maybe you can just tell me from scratch how I should arrange those elements in CSS, so that I get the arrangement I need?

Thank you!

Comment: please set up a plnkr.co

Comment: Can you show us the preview? A screen shot can also work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have forgotten to set the position attribute for the content div? z-index only works on elements with fixed, absolute or relative position. (the default is static position, so the z-index is not working)

No idea why the other elements are covered. Maybe posting the css as well would help.